# How to open a PacketCommunicator twice to set different filters for each?

Tags: c#, pcap, winpcap

When I open `PacketCommunicator` the second time it overlaps the first.

How to open a `PacketCommunicator` twice to set **different filters** for each?

my code:

```
PacketCommunicator communicator = selectedDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000);
communicator.SetFilter(filter1);

PacketCommunicator communicator2 = selectedDevice.Open(65536, PacketDeviceOpenAttributes.Promiscuous, 1000);
communicator2.SetFilter(filter2);
```